# Some CSS works in WAMP but not when I upload it to the server

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a website using Twitter Bootstrap 3.2

I have a sortable portfolio and the active link needs to be indicated. So i added this to my CSS.

```
#filter li {
   color: #428BCA;
}
#filter li:hover,
#filter li:focus,
#filter li:active,
#filter li.active
{
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

This works fine in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE) when i test it on WAMP but doesn't work when the same CSS file is uploaded on the server.
I have cleared cache for all browsers. Other elements in the same CSS file work just fine.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="row">

        <ul id="filter" class="list-inline">
            <li class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn" role="button">all</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn" role="button">commercials</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn" role="button">movies</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn" role="button">music-videos</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn" role="button">non-fiction</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is the Js script if it is needed.

```
<script>
$('ul#filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#filter .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('ul#portfolios li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('ul#portfolios li').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                    } else {
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                        }
                        });
            }
            return false;
            });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a longshot, but: are you sure you don't have multiple elements with the same ID "filter"?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have uploaded the HTML DIV as well for your perusal. My CSS is just 80 lines. No conflicts I guess. Come to think of it, it works with WAMP but not on the server...

Comment: And now, just like that it has started working. Thanks for your help Smuuf.

Comment: Well, weird. :D Farewell!